# Create data frame from TEI XML using xml2

Tags: xml, r, dataframe, tei, xml2

I'm trying to create a data frame of an TEI-XML version of Moby Dick using Hadley Wickham's `xml2` package. I want the data frame to ultimately look like this (for all the words in the novel):

```
df <- data.frame(
chapter = c("1", "1", "1"),
words = c("call", "me", "ishmael"))
```

I'm able to get pieces, but not the whole thing. Here's what I've got so far:

```
library("xml2")

# Read file
melville <- read_xml("data/melville.xml")

# Get chapter divs (remember, doesn't include epilogue)
chap_frames <- xml_find_all(melville, "//d1:div1[@type='chapter']", xml_ns(melville))
```

This gives us a list with a length of 134 (that is, each of the chapters). We can get the chapter number for a specific element as follow:

```
xml_attr(chap_frames[[1]], "n")
```

We can get the paragraphs of a specific chapter (that is, minus the chapter heading) as follows:

```
words <- xml_find_all(chap_frames[[1]], ".//d1:p", xml_ns(melville)) %>%  # remember doesn't include epilogue
xml_text()
```

And we can get the words of the chapters as follows:

```
# Split words function
split_words <- function (ll) {
  result <- unlist(strsplit(ll, "\\W+"))
  result <- result[result != ""]
  tolower(result)
}

# Apply function
words <- split_words(words)
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the chapter number for each of the words. I had a toy example that worked:

```
mini <- read_xml(
'
<div1 type="chapter" n="1" id="_75784">
<head>Loomings</head>
    <p rend="fiction">Call me Ishmael.</p>
    <p rend="fiction">There now is your insular city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian isles by coral reefs- commerce surrounds it with her surf.</p> 
</div1>
')

# Function
process_chap <- function(div){
chapter <- xml_attr(div, "n")
words <- xml_find_all(div, "//p") %>%
    xml_text()
data.frame(chapter = chapter,
           word = split_words(words))
}

process_chap(mini)
```

But it doesn't work for the longer example

```
 process_chap2 <- function(div){
 chapter <- xml_attr(div, "n")
 words <- xml_find_all(div, ".//d1:p", xml_ns(melville)) %>%  # remember doesn't include epilogue
 xml_text()
 data.frame(chapter = chapter,
           word = split_words(words))
}

# Fails because there are more words than chapter names
df <- process_chap2(chap_frames)

# Gives all the words p (not chapters), chapter numbers are `NULL`. 
df2 <- process_chap2(melville)
```

(I know why toy example works but the Melville ones doesn't, but I wanted to include it to show what I'm trying to do). I'm guessing I might need a loop of some sort, but I'm not sure where to begin. Any suggestions?

PS: I'm not entirely sure if I should link to an xml version of Moby Dick I found on Github, but you can find it easily enough searching for `melville1.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is to grap the data for each chapter one at a time. Then combine the words of one chapter together with the chapter number into a data frame. R will repeat the single value for the chapter number as often as needed:

```
words <- letters[1:3]
n     <- 1

df <- data.frame(words, n)

df
##  words n
## 1     a 1
## 2     b 1
## 3     c 1
```

Having gathered the information for all your chapters in neat data frames you can then use `rbind()` to combine the whole into one data frame.

That's how this might look like for the first two chapters of your data ....

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


# Read file
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reganna/TextAnalysisWithR/master/data/XML1/melville1.xml"
melville <- read_xml(url)


# get chapter frame and number
chap_frames <- xml_find_all(melville, "//d1:div1[@type='chapter']", xml_ns(melville))
chap_n <- xml_attr(chap_frames, "n")


# get the date for first chapter
words1 <- 
  xml_find_all(chap_frames[[1]], ".//d1:p", xml_ns(melville))  %>% 
    xml_text() %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    str_split("\\W+") %>% 
    unlist()  %>% 
    tolower()

n1 <- xml_attr(chap_frames[[1]], "n")


# get the data for the second chapter
words2 <- 
  xml_find_all(chap_frames[[2]], ".//d1:p", xml_ns(melville))  %>% 
  xml_text() %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_split("\\W+") %>% 
  unlist()  %>% 
  tolower()

n2 <- xml_attr(chap_frames[[2]], "n")


# put it together
df <- 
  rbind(
    data_frame(words=words1, chapter=n1),
    data_frame(words=words2, chapter=n2)
  )
df


## Source: local data frame [3,719 x 2]
## 
##      words chapter
## 1     call       1
## 2       me       1
## 3  ishmael       1
## 4     some       1
## 5    years       1
## 6      ago       1
## 7    never       1
## 8     mind       1
## 9      how       1
## 10    long       1
## ..     ...     ...
```

To do this more efficient for all your chapters you might build a loop that repeats the steps for all chapters or you might consider a function that does the extraction, apply it to all chapters and then combine the data via `rbind()` later on.

... I would probably do it like that:

```
# building function
extract_data <- function(chapter_frame){
  words <- 
    xml_find_all(chapter_frame, ".//d1:p", xml_ns(melville))  %>% 
    xml_text() %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    str_split("\\W+") %>% 
    unlist()  %>% 
    tolower()
  n   <- xml_attr(chapter_frame, "n")
  pos <- seq_along(words)
  data_frame(words, chapter=n, paragraph=pos)
}

# using function
chapter_words <- 
  lapply(chap_frames, extract_data) 

# `rbind()`ing data
chapter_words <- do.call(rbind, chapter_words)

chapter_words
## Source: local data frame [216,669 x 3]
## 
##      words chapter  paragraph
## 1     call       1          1
## 2       me       1          2
## 3  ishmael       1          3
## 4     some       1          4
## 5    years       1          5        
## 6      ago       1          6
## 7    never       1          7
## 8     mind       1          8
## 9      how       1          9
## 10    long       1         10 
## ..     ...     ...        ...
```